# Asterisk intermittent 3sec audio loss, logs out of order

Tags: asterisk

I have an Asterisk server that serves upwards of 450 agents, it's been in production for a little over a year. Every once and a while we experience bouts of 3 seconds worth of lost audio, followed by 1 sec of garbled audio. Flow data and Wireshark playback shows it's originating from this system.  The symptom discovered today is, during these short periods of audio problems the log records are out of order, that is the second in the timestamp jumps around forward and backwards. In the RTP captures, the 1 second of garbled audio consists of many "Wrong Timestamp" markers.

In the log below, you'll see it jump around between 12:20:45 and 12:20:48.

**Log snipit:**

```
[2014-08-20 12:20:44] DEBUG[14835] devicestate.c: Changing state for SIP/SIP/peertrunk4-0000211d - state 4 (Invalid)
[2014-08-20 12:20:44] DEBUG[14854] app_queue.c: Device 'SIP/SIP/peertrunk4-0000211d' changed to state '4' (Invalid) but we don't care because they'r$
[2014-08-20 12:20:44] DEBUG[7558] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:44] DEBUG[26007] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[27190] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[14853] chan_sip.c: = No match Their Call ID: 178f1fb01ee44c39299de3af40b487c9@10.200.5.7 Their Tag  Our tag: as28e70c40
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[26897] app_dial.c: Dunno what to do with control type 25
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[7558] res_musiconhold.c: SIP/peertrunk3-000013d1 Opened file 0 '/home/asterisk/env/agentwaiting/agent-waiting-long'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[7558] rtp.c: Difference is 31288, ms is 3931
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[27244] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[24681] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[24578] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 44 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] WARNING[26897] channel.c: Exceptionally long voice queue length queuing to Local/NPANXXXXXX@celeus-3920,1
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[23512] channel.c: Scheduling timer at 0 sample intervals
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] channel.c: Stopped silence generator on 'SIP/peertrunk3-00001029'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] channel.c: Set channel SIP/peertrunk3-00001029 to write format gsm
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[15150] manager.c: Manager received command 'StopMonitor'
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[27025] channel.c: Scheduling timer at 138 sample intervals
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[15150] channel.c: Avoiding initial deadlock for channel '0x7f31c8787b10'
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[26717] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[27356] channel.c: Scheduling timer at 0 sample intervals
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] channel.c: Scheduling timer at 0 sample intervals
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] channel.c: Scheduling timer at 0 sample intervals
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[15150] channel.c: Avoiding initial deadlock for channel '0x7f31c8787b10'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] chan_agent.c: Waited for stream, result '0'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] chan_agent.c: Set read format, result '0'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] chan_agent.c: Set write format, result '0'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] devicestate.c: Notification of state change to be queued on device/channel Agent/436
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[26724] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 44 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] VERBOSE[27356] logger.c: [2014-08-20 12:20:48]     -- Called Agent/436
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[27356] devicestate.c: No provider found, checking channel drivers for Agent - 436
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[15150] channel.c: Avoiding initial deadlock for channel '0x7f31c8787b10'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] channel.c: Set channel SIP/peertrunk3-00001029 to write format slin
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] channel.c: Scheduling timer at 160 sample intervals
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] channel.c: Started silence generator on 'SIP/peertrunk3-00001029'
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] rtp.c: Difference is 30512, ms is 3834
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] DEBUG[23512] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[18409] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[12607] res_musiconhold.c: SIP/peertrunk3-00002937 Opened file 0 '/home/asterisk/env/agentwaiting/agent-waiting-long'
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[26469] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 44 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[26877] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:45] DEBUG[26002] rtp.c: Got RTCP report of 64 bytes
[2014-08-20 12:20:48] VERBOSE[27356] logger.c: [2014-08-20 12:20:48]     -- Agent/436 answered Local/NPANXXXXXX@celeus-bccf,1
```

The environment:

- VMware HA cluster, services around 50 VMs
- ESXi 5.1
- No over committed resources & CPU/Disk IO allocations are set to 'High' for this VM
- CentOS 6.5
- Asterisk C.3.7.2 (Business Edition, 1.4 trunk)
- vmware-tools is current
- host timesync, instead of NTPd

I don't see anything funny in the historic or real-time stats vCenter is feeding me, although I fully admit I may be looking in all the wrong places. Plus, those 3 second anomalies probably average out in the graphs.

I'm assuming whatever is causing the log to get out of order is also causing the dropped audio. I have been unable to find any references to out of order log entries in my searches. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like issue with time re-synced. Asterisk not writed with posibility of time change in mind, becuase it designed to work on common hardware.

Can suggest following

1) Get rid of vmware, put on hardware host

OR

2) disable host timesync, put instead ntp. Increase cpu resources for host.

Comment: CPU resources aside (ESXi 5.1 doesn't provide me finer granuality than I am alrady taking advantage of), both of your suggestions have already been considered. It's good to hear the same feedback as my suspicions.

My remaining steps are:
1) Disable home timesync, enable NTPd
2) Disable NTPd, run ntpdate once a day
3) Ditch VMware

Comment: Asterisk is nto designed to be workign in vm. ESXi is not designed for realtime. Can do nothing here.

Comment: Exactly, this was fully understood before we setup it up like this. Most of the time, virtual asterisk has been "good enough" but I feel we're about to hit a _timing_ wall I simply cannot overcome.

Comment: Time change have be less then 50ms in a row. Increase change frequency or fix you ESXi settings/density.